# How to get the column name and row name of a tablecell by clicking on the cell in angular4?

Tags: angular, html-table

I would like to console log the column name and the row name of my clicked cell. I have created the following table, where the click event works for the 'timesroom' but not for the 'weekday' which gives an undefined response.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let weekday of weekdays">
                <div>{{weekday}}</div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr scope="row" *ngFor="let time of times"><td>{{time}}</td>
            <th scope="row"></th> 
            <td (click) = "onClick(weekday, time)"></td>
            <td (click) = "onClick(weekday, time)"></td>
            <td (click) = "onClick(weekday, time)"></td>
            <td (click) = "onClick(weekday, time)"></td>
            <td (click) = "onClick(weekday, time)"></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
</table>
```

I believe the problem which I am facing is that the 'weekday' is out of scope. My question is how I should modify my code to be able to print both the 'weekday' and the 'time' on a cell click?

Comment: as you have NOT for inside for, you can use onClick(0,time), onClick(1,time)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repeat your `td`'s using `*ngFor` and pass `weekday` into onClick handler

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th *ngFor="let weekday of weekdays">
      <div>{{weekday}}</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
....
<tr *ngFor="let time of times">
    <td>{{time}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let weekday of weekdays" (click) = "onClick(weekday, time)"></td>
 </tr>
....
```

Comment: I changed and the result is that the columns 3 column right, so when I click on wednesday cells it prints Mondays.

Comment: because you have two manual columns: <td>{{time}}</td>
            <th scope="row"></th>

Comment: Check edits in my answer. In first column you need to display time, that's right?

Answer (score 0):

The code which work for me is the following:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let weekday of weekdays">
                <div>{{weekday}}</div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr scope="row" *ngFor="let time of times"><td>{{time}}</td>
            <th scope="row" *ngFor="let weekday of weekdaysForClick" (click) = "onClick(weekday, time)"></th> 
          </tr>
         </tbody>
</table>
```

I differentiate between two arrays: weekdays for the colum name which are the following( #, Monday, Thusday, Wednesday...) and weekdaysForClick(Monday, Thusday, Wednesday...).